# Python Web Scraping: urllib.request.urlopen hangs

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, urllib

I am trying to scrape a website using the following code. 
However the function doesn't ever return (I suspect because robots are blocked on the website). Any workarounds?

```py
import urllib.request
url = "https://www.nseindia.com/option-chain"
req = urllib.request.Request(
    url, 
    data=None, 
    headers={
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.47 Safari/537.36'
    }
)
response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
html = response.read()
print(html)
```

Answer (score 0):

It works if you change the user-agent(I have used postman):

```
import urllib.request
url = "https://www.nseindia.com/option-chain"
req = urllib.request.Request(
    url, 
    data=None, 
    headers={
        'User-Agent':"PostmanRuntime/7.6.0"
    }
)
response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
html = response.read()
print(html)
```